# How to estimate transaction fee without initializing a signer in taquito?

Tags: taquito

I am trying to estimate the fees for a transaction call using the `Tezos.estimate.transfer()` function but it is asking to initialize a signer. Is it possible to make an estimate call without a signer or private key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does tezos-client compute a transaction fee?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-does-tezos-client-compute-a-transaction-fee)

Comment: @utdrmac not exactly, I know the rpc endpoint to make the query. But I am looking for a solution to do this with taquito.

Comment: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2733/how-to-calculate-tezos-fees

Comment: This question has been asked many times. Please use the search feature.

Comment: Thanks @utdrmac for pointing out these resources, but I have to disagree, there are surely question on how to calculate tx fee. But what I am looking for is specific to this npm package called Taquito. None of the answers provide the solution I am looking. I guess I will have to use the raw rpc calls directly.

Comment: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/how-to-estimate-baker-and-storage-fee-with-taquito-for-a-contract

Comment: @utdrmac did you read the question or you just pasted the first 4 threads you could find?

Comment: I read the question. I commented. Thanks for your assistance in helping to provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below code will help you.

```
const TezosToolkit = require('@taquito/taquito').TezosToolkit;
const tezos = new TezosToolkit("TEZOS NODE RPC URL");
const InMemorySigner = require('@taquito/signer').InMemorySigner;

const estimateTxn = async function(input){
    tezos.setProvider({ signer: new InMemorySigner(input.senderPrivateKey) });
    const estimated = await tezos.estimate
                .transfer({ to: input.destination, amount: Number(input.amount)/1000000 })
                .then((est) => {
                    const estimated = {
                        "gasLimit"     :   est.gasLimit.toString(),
                        "storageLimit" :   est.storageLimit.toString(),
                        "suggestedFee" :   est.suggestedFeeMutez.toString()
                    }
                    return estimated;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("ERROR: Estimation failed!!",error);
                });
    return estimated;
}
```

Here the input is:

```
const input = {
    "destination"       :   "address of receiver",
    "amount"            :   "amount in tez",
    "source"            :   "address of sender",
    "senderPublicKey"   :   "public key of sender",   
    "senderPrivateKey"  :   "private key of sender"
}
```

Comment: The question specifically mentions that I want to estimate the tx fees without initializing the signer, please read the question before providing an answer. Thanks